# JS regex.exec() returning first find

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn how to break up this string:

```
var str = 'red','blue','gree'
```

I have this working code:

```
var clean = str.replace(/\'/g, "");
var elements = clean.split(',');
```

which produces array `["red","blue","green"]` which is what i want however. id like to learn how to do this using regex.exec() method.

here is what i got:

```
var patt = /([^']+)/g;
var elem= patt.exec(str);
```

but this returns array `["red","red"]`

any ideas?

Comment: I suggest you stick to `split`. RegEx is overkill for this task.

Comment: What is this: `var str = 'red','blue','gree'`?   I doubt it is doing what you intend.  Do you mean for it to be a single string like this: `var str = "'red','blue','gree'";`?  Or an array of strings like this: `var str = ['red','blue','gree'];`

Answer (score 2):

With `exec`, to get multiple matches, you need to run it in a loop...

```
var str = "'red','blue','gree'"; // making a guess here

var patt = /([^']+)/g;
var match;

       //   v----yes, an assignment
while(match = patt.exec(str)) {
    console.log(match[1]);
}
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/D62D4/

The global regex stores on itself the index past the end of the last match, and performs the next query starting at that point.

This goes on until there's no match, at which point the index is set back to `0`.

You can observe and modify this index on the regex using the `.lastIndex` property.